# ASP.NET Hide Site (in URL)

Tags: asp.net, url

When I navigate through my Website and access a new Site, by example:

```
Default.aspx
```

it would show in the URL-Bar: `www.mySite.com/Default.aspx`

But I want to **hide** this! -> So each time, it should stay: `www.mySite.com`

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want *every* page to have your main domain name only in the url, you could create a frame in your index page (f.ex. Default.aspx, or even better index.html):

```
<frameset>
    <frame src="default2.aspx">
</frameset>
```

and then create your new startpage in default2.aspx.

However, frames have disadvantages, and your visitors wouldn't be able to copy the url - they would always return to your startpage.

Comment: where to put this code? In the Markup of Default.aspx? And delete everything else?

Comment: This code is the replacement for the `body` tag in your html index file, so be sure to replace just the `<body>....</body>` part.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at routing. Routing will enable you to add a path like www.mySite.com to a specific aspx file.

It's quit easy to setup in your global.asax :) You can check the following url for some info [ASP.NET routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

Comment: I created the Global.asax and added some Code, but I don't know really what I have to do...